# Slow startup of xamarin app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, cross-platform, app-startup

We are developing a cross platform app on a PCL, but for the time being we are only using android devices for testing.
Our concern is that its taking about 6 to 8 seconds (depending on which device we test it) to start the app, which is very slow.
After placing a few breakpoints we saw that the timing is consumed pretty evenly.
We did notice this particular parts took longer:

- 1s before reaching onCreate() on MainActivity (there's a splash screen before which only has one image and a background color)
- 1s on `base.OnCreate(bundle);`
- 1s on `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);`
- 1.5s on `Page mainPage = new LogScreen();` (creating the main page to then set it as main navigation page).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll put together all the solutions we found for this, so its all in one place.

One of the answers linked **[this](https://blog.xamarin.com/5-ways-boost-xamarin-forms-app-startup-time/)** post, which was **very** useful.

Besides that we also did the following things:

- Check "**optimize code**" box on Properties in all projects. Not sure if that improves startup time specifically but it seems to help on the general performance a bit.
- Add **AOT and LLVM**. We found a way to do this even though the option isn't available on our IDE. This increases the build time by a lot so if you want to do it I'd recommend doing it only for release builds.
- Enable **Xamarin Fast Renders**. This is an experimental thing so you should read some documentation about it, but its done by adding this line `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("FastRenderers_Experimental");` on `MainActivity.OnCreate()` method, before `global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);`
- **Update our Xamarin.Forms Nuget** Version. This needs to be the same version on all projects of your solution, we had some issues with tap gestures which where also improved by this.
- **Link SDK Assemblies**. On Properties > Android Options under Linking you can set to link "SDK Assemblies Only". You can also set to all assemblies, but this is not recommended if you are using custom assemblies.
- **Pre-Load screens**. This improved by a lot the performance on the app itself what we did is load on each screen, on background, the views and view-models that where needed next, so when pushing them onto the navigation stack they were already loaded. This reduced by a lot the time on transition between pages.

Answer (score 8):

First thing I would recommend is to not benchmark a debug build of your app, the code paths of the Mono runtime and Jit'd code are not the same as a release build, the use of shared runtimes, assembly sizes, etc, etc, etc. will all effect the startup and execution times.

Here are examples of startup times of a "very large" aggressively tuned Android Forms-based app on high-end and low-end devices using an in-house benchmarker (conditionally compiled in, not injected, and using the OS's system clock).

#### App Overview:

- Xamarin.Forms v2.4.0.269-pre2
- Mix of coded and XAML based Pages, Controls, etc...
- XAML Compiler enabled
- "Splash screen" disabled

  - A Theme-based splash on `MainActivity` will add:

    - 200+ milliseconds to startup times on a fast device,
    - 1-2 seconds on a device w/ slow flash access
  - Just do not use an Activity-based splash-screen ;-)
- Multi-dex'd
- Proguard'd (aggressively reduced jars via UI testing w/ auto-feedback loop)
- Linker (Link All, aggressively reduced assembly sizes with a custom link description file generated via UI testing w/ auto-feedback)
- 100% source-built to allow collapsing namespaces and assembly reduction
- Viper architecture w/ no 3rd-party DI/IoC
- Lazy-loaded design using data, resource ad network priority queues
- Realm live objects and queries used for all data (DB min. size: 250MB, max. size 1.2GB)

Times are generated via a shell script that reboots the devices, monitors the startup to wait for the system to settle, launches a series of apps (GApps, Facebook, Instagram, Twitter, etc...), waits for the system to settle, and then launches the Forms app via:

```
export deviceTime=$(echo "$(adb -s $deviceID shell cat /proc/uptime | awk '{print $1}') * 1000" | bc -l)
adb -s $deviceID shell am start -n com.sushihangover.GeneticCancerDNAMapper/com.sushihangover.GeneticCancerDNAMapper.DevOpsDashboard --el startTime ${deviceTime%.*}
```

#### Google Pixel (Oreo-based) device (app is usable in ~430ms):

```
I GeneticCancerDNAMapper: 0.162 : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.OnCreate
I GeneticCancerDNAMapper: 0.164 : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.base.SetTheme
I GeneticCancerDNAMapper: 0.201 : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.base.OnCreate
I GeneticCancerDNAMapper: 0.244 : Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init
I GeneticCancerDNAMapper: 0.266 : Realms.Realm.GetInstanceAsync ~Get Instance & Data~
I GeneticCancerDNAMapper: 0.324 : Realms.Realm.GetInstanceAsync ~Obtained Instance & Data~
I GeneticCancerDNAMapper: 0.324 : Xamarin.Forms.Application Content
I GeneticCancerDNAMapper: 0.349 : Xamarin.Forms.Application Content ~Creation Completed~
I GeneticCancerDNAMapper: 0.353 : Xamarin.Forms.Application.MainPage ~Displayed~
I GeneticCancerDNAMapper: 0.43 : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.LoadApplication
```

#### Low-end "Android One" 512MB device w/ ***very slow*** flash (app is usable in ~4.5s):

Re: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_One

```
I/GeneticCancerDNAMapper(10904): 2.453 : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.OnCreate
I/GeneticCancerDNAMapper(10904): 2.467 : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.base.SetTheme
I/GeneticCancerDNAMapper(10904): 2.731 : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.base.OnCreate
I/GeneticCancerDNAMapper(10904): 3.016 : Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init
I/GeneticCancerDNAMapper(10904): 3.166 : Realms.Realm.GetInstanceAsync ~Get Instance & Data~
I/GeneticCancerDNAMapper(10904): 3.571 : Realms.Realm.GetInstanceAsync ~Obtained Instance & Data~
I/GeneticCancerDNAMapper(10904): 3.571 : Xamarin.Forms.Application Content
I/GeneticCancerDNAMapper(10904): 3.772 : Xamarin.Forms.Application Content ~Creation Completed~
I/GeneticCancerDNAMapper(10904): 3.799 : Xamarin.Forms.Application.MainPage ~Displayed~
I/GeneticCancerDNAMapper(10904): 4.457 : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.LoadApplication
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a common problem while using Xamarin.Forms there are many threads related to this specially this one:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/93178/lets-talk-performance/p6

The good news is that the Xamarin team is working on it.

Here are some tips you can do improve it:

https://blog.xamarin.com/5-ways-boost-xamarin-forms-app-startup-time/

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this. For example we have 5 tabs. And we have 5 viewmodel or 5 codebehind. Every tabs viewmodels constructors we defined start timer method. And first tab constructor initialize 700ms after timer start. And second tab is starting 1 seconds after. Lets code for this:

First tab Home and home viewmodel is HomeViewModel.

```
public void HomeTimer()
{
    timer.Interval = 700;

    timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => OnTimedEvent(sender, e);

    timer.AutoReset = false;

    timer.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Enabled = false;

    Yap(); // yap command all the page listview and get api.
}
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

public HomeViewModel()
{
    HomeTimer(); // hometimer starting
}
```

And second tab is MyPage and viewmodel is MyPageViewModel and constructor is the same:

```
public void MyPageTimer()
{
    timer.Interval = 1000; //look. home page starting 0.7 seconds after and mypage starting 1 seconds after.

    timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => OnTimedEvent(sender, e);

    timer.AutoReset = false;

    timer.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Enabled = false;

    GetMypage(); // and getmypage method all the initialize the page and listview and webapi works.
}
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

public MyPageViewModel()
{
    MyPageTimer();
}
```

And this operation i delete 1 second from startup. Before this operation my app starting 3.2 second and now starting 2.2 second.