# Xamarin.forms - long time of running the application

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am developing an application with xamarin forms.. Its simple mvvm application. I just started to learn xamarin language.

For now I am wondering how can I decrease time of run the application. Even blank app is starting for 3-4 sec..

If there is no way to decrease this timie, then xamarin.forms is pretty poor technology :/

Tested on android 4.4.2 api 19 and android 5.1.0 api 22. In both cases result is same. (I am doing this on real device not emulator)

Is there any way to optimalize that?

Btw. I use the newest version of xamarin and visual studio.

Comment: You could check this https://blog.xamarin.com/5-ways-boost-xamarin-forms-app-startup-time/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slow startup of xamarin app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46163504/slow-startup-of-xamarin-app)

Answer (score 0):

It's known issue for such a long time that XF/Android starting time is too long.
Xamarin team also have tried figure out for a long time.